# URL representation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, url, database

I wonder how to efficiently store a website URL in a database (mongoDB in my case)...

The problem:
It should be indexed to achieve fast query performance but mongo allows indexes on fields smaller than 1024 bytes "only".

I thought about hashing or base64 to shrink the URL... but since I use
a single threaded webserver (node.js) I don't want to do heavy stuff on it...

Are there any good ideas about other ways to achieve this (the alternative representation
should be unique...)?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I think 1024 characters is a very long URL. Are you sure you're going to reach that limit? If you have any control over those URLs you should probably make sure they are shorter than that.

Comment: Thanks for participating.

I have no influence on the length of the URLs and I cannot short them - nevertheless I think that shorter content in datafields should help to keep the index small... (just a guess) so hashing the URLs seems to be more reasonable than using the full length of 1024 bytes (for some URLs) or heavy changes in lenght... Can someone confirm that for mangoDB?

Comment: That's correct. Smaller values on indexed fields should lead to a smaller index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very question comes up during 10gen's MongoDB training and hashing is presented as the viable solution. Generating an MD5 hash for a URL shouldn't be computationally intensive. I definitely wouldn't suggest base64-encoding, as that's only going to expand the URL string.

The goal is to create an index with high cardinality, but that doesn't mean the hashes have to be unique. If you include both the hash and URL in your query, you'll take advantage of the highly-selective hash index and then MongoDB will match the URL among the index hits. In the following example, let's pretend there is a hash collision for both URL's:

```
$ mongo --quiet
> db.urls.insert({_id: 1, url: "http://google.com", hash: "c7b920f"});
> db.urls.insert({_id: 2, url: "http://yahoo.com", hash: "c7b920f"});
> db.urls.find({hash: "c7b920f"})
{ "_id" : 1, "url" : "http://google.com", "hash" : "c7b920f" }
{ "_id" : 2, "url" : "http://yahoo.com", "hash" : "c7b920f" }

> db.urls.find({hash: "c7b920f", url: "http://google.com"})
{ "_id" : 1, "url" : "http://google.com", "hash" : "c7b920f" }

> db.urls.ensureIndex({hash: 1})
> db.urls.find({hash: "c7b920f", url: "http://google.com"}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor hash_1",
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "n" : 1,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "hash" : [
            [
                "c7b920f",
                "c7b920f"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "localhost:27017"
}
```

I'm not sure if you have additional business requirements to guarantee URL uniqueness throughout the collection, but the example above is just to show that it isn't necessary from a querying standpoint. Of course, any hash algorithm is going to have some chance of collision, but you have better options than MD5 that would still satisfy the 1024-byte limit.

Comment: Thanks for the great input! Setting an index on the hash and use the URL to choose the unique entry is a great idea... because I am a bit worried about calculating an MD5 hash (I have to do it on every request) I am looking for simpler and faster non-cryptographic hash-algorythms... to avoid compute intensive tasks in the node.js environment...